# Can select using dblink, cannot insert using dblink

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I have inherited a code which helps me to fetch data from external systems. It is a bit screwed up, but I have to use it as is.

```
   SELECT NVL (
                (
                  SELECT TRIM (alias.SERV_CD)
                   FROM schema.CX_SER@db_link alias
                  WHERE     row_id =
                                          (
                                           SELECT mix.par_row_id
                                              FROM schema.CX_SER_MI_XM@db_link mix
                                             WHERE     mix.bill = SA.BILL_AC
                                          AND ROWNUM < 2
                                          )
                        AND ROWNUM < 2
                        ),
                (
                    SELECT TRIM (ba.SERV_CD)
                     FROM schema.s_some_table@db_link ba
                     WHERE ba.row_id = sa.BILL_AC AND ROWNUM < 2
                )
            ) REQUIRED_CODE,                   --NVL ends here
             COUNT (*) order_count,
             TRUNC (ia.CREATED_DATE) CREATED_DATE_date,
             TRUNC (ia.CREATED_DATE + 1) inserted_date
        FROM schema.s_some_table@db_link sa, schema.action_table@db_link ia, schema.s_order@db_link ord
       WHERE     ia.CREATED_DATE >= TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1)
             AND ia.CREATED_DATE < TRUNC (SYSDATE)
             AND ord.status = 'Done'
    GROUP BY SA.BILL_AC, TRUNC (ia.CREATED_DATE), TRUNC (IA.CREATED_DATE + 1);
```

The said code returns results when I run the select as is.
But when I try to insert these records in my schema(using simple `insert into(columns) <this select statement>`, I get the following error messages :

1. Error: ORA-00904:"SA"."BILL_ACC" :invalid identifier.
   ORA - 02063 : preceding line from db_link.

A select statement like :

```
  with c as(
      SELECT NVL (
                    (
                      SELECT TRIM (alias.SERV_CD)
                       FROM schema.CX_SER@db_link alias
                      WHERE     row_id =
                                              (
                                               SELECT mix.par_row_id
                                                  FROM schema.CX_SER_MI_XM@db_link mix
                                                 WHERE     mix.bill = SA.BILL_AC
                                              AND ROWNUM < 2
                                              )
                            AND ROWNUM < 2
                            ),
                    (
                        SELECT TRIM (ba.SERV_CD)
                         FROM schema.s_some_table@db_link ba
                         WHERE ba.row_id = sa.BILL_AC AND ROWNUM < 2
                    )
                ) REQUIRED_CODE,                   --NVL ends here
                 COUNT (*) order_count,
                 TRUNC (ia.CREATED_DATE) CREATED_DATE_date,
                 TRUNC (ia.CREATED_DATE + 1) inserted_date
            FROM schema.s_some_table@db_link sa, schema.action_table@db_link ia, schema.s_order@db_link ord
           WHERE     ia.CREATED_DATE >= TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1)
                 AND ia.CREATED_DATE < TRUNC (SYSDATE)
                 AND ord.status = 'Done'
        GROUP BY SA.BILL_AC, TRUNC (ia.CREATED_DATE), TRUNC (IA.CREATED_DATE + 1)) 
    select * from c where REQUIRED_CODE IS NOT NULL;
```

**also fail with same error**. However, I am able to obtain results when I query using some other column in above `with` clause statement gives results, for e.g `where order_count>2` **gives result**. So the problem is in the REQUIRED_CODE section, and maybe, in the group by.

Please guide on the course of action. I need to insert the records flowing into my schema.

**NOTE** : All columns are either varchar2 or date

Comment: Sounds like it's being rewritten in a way that has too many levels of subquery. You might be able to trace it see what it's doing. Just for fun, does the CTE work if you add a `/*+ MATERIALIZED */` hint, right after the first `SELECT` keyword?

Comment: @AlexPoole, no, it does not.

Comment: No, but the 'preceding line from db_link' means the bit that's passed to the remove DB to evaluate is tripping over, probably in the nested subquery, It may just be from the CTE/insert changing the driving site, but I can't remember how to check; looking at the execution plans might be a start. Also trying to think how to replicate this *8-)

Comment: Looks like you can fix the CTE with by adding a `/*+ DRIVING_SITE (sa) */` hint inside that, but the insert doesn't like that. Which makes some sense I suppose. A workaround would be to bulk collect and insert forall in a PL/SQL block, but that doesn't seem very satisfactory.

Comment: Attempting to rewrite the query to use ANSI joins and avoid the subqueries seems to cure it, but the obfuscated table names and lack of join conditions make it hard to be sure I'm doing it right. And I'm not sure if "I have to use it as is" means that won't help anyway for some reason. There are some bugs on MOS that might be relevant, or at least make it worth raising an SR, if you can't rewrite it.

Comment: @AlexPoole, thanks for your inputs. In case you have tried rewriting, do post, will modify if possible, and try to push. Who doesn't like a better solution! Also, will try out your other suggestions, and update in 12 hours(away now). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my attempt to replicate the issue has ended up close to yours, you can avoid the error with the CTE by adding [a `driving_site` hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50704):

```
with c as (
   SELECT /*+ DRIVING_SITE (sa) */ NVL (
...
```

That prevents the query being written and distributed in a way that confuses the optimiser; I think it's tripping over the nested reference to `SA` in the subquery and it's ending up too many levels down to be recognised.

That hint doesn't have any effect on the insert though.

As mentioned in comments I've had a quick go at rewriting the query to avoid the subqueries. It's a bit rough and I'm not sure I understand everything you're currently doing, partly because of the table name changes etc. But you wanted to see it, and it might give you something to work from...

```
   INSERT INTO t42
  SELECT NVL (TRIM(MIN(t.SERV_CD) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY NULL)),
           TRIM(MIN(ba.SERV_CD) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY NULL))
         ) REQUIRED_CODE,  --NVL ends here
         COUNT (*) order_count,
         TRUNC (ia.CREATED_DATE) CREATED_DATE_date,
         TRUNC (ia.CREATED_DATE + 1) inserted_date
    FROM schema.s_some_table@db_link sa
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT mix.bill, alias.SERV_CD
        FROM schema.CX_SER_MI_XM@db_link mix
        JOIN schema.CX_SER@db_link alias
          ON alias.row_id = mix.par_row_id
      ) t
      ON t.bill = SA.BILL_ACC
    LEFT JOIN schema.s_some_table@db_link ba
      ON ba.row_id = sa.BILL_ACC
    CROSS JOIN schema.action_table@db_link ia
    CROSS JOIN schema.s_order@db_link ord
   WHERE     ia.CREATED_DATE >= TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1)
         AND ia.CREATED_DATE < TRUNC (SYSDATE)
         AND ord.status = 'Done'
GROUP BY SA.BILL_ACC, TRUNC (ia.CREATED_DATE), TRUNC (IA.CREATED_DATE + 1);
```

If you can't get it working then you could use your original query in a PL/SQL block, either as a cursor and doing row-by-row inserts, or preferably (particularly if it will return a lot of data) using a collection with `bulk collect` and a `forall` insert.

If you search My Oracle Support for ORA-02063 and ORA-00904 you'll see quite a few bugs, some of which seem to apply to 11g but ought to have been fixed by my version 11.2.0.4; I can't see anything that quite matches from a quick browse but it's possible you are hitting one of those, or indeed one that hasn't been reported. It may be worth raising an SR to investigate your specific scenario.

Comment: Using bulk collect solved my issue.  Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @I_am_Batman - I've OK'd  your edit to match your question edit, but your names seemed pretty obscure already. It might be helpful for someone else seeing the same issue to see that it might be possible to rewrite a query to avoid the error, even if the specifis of your query are not relevant.

Comment: Alex, I noticed you are the approver. Yes, they were intended to be obscure,and now I am satisfied. Let your answer remain as is.Cheers